# Application crashs when I try to view the entries of in a multiple tables Database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I created two table `weekone` and `weektwo` in my database. They a both uploaded the data in the database succussfully taken from `EditTexts`, however when I want to view the database by pressing `View`button, the application crashes.

This is how i am saving entries from Editext in database in table `weekone`

```
String treadmillTimings = durOnTreadmill.getText().toString();

                DatabaseManager entry = new DatabaseManager(this);
                entry.open();
                entry.createEntry(treadmillTimings);
                entry.close();

                String stepperTimings = durOnStepper.getText().toString();

                DatabaseManager entry1 = new DatabaseManager(this);
                entry1.open();
                entry1.week1createEntry1(stepperTimings);
                entry1.close();

                String stationaryRowingTimings = durOnStationaryRowing.getText().toString();

                DatabaseManager entry2 = new DatabaseManager(this);
                entry2.open();
                entry2.week1createEntry2(stationaryRowingTimings);
                entry2.close();

                String exerciseBikeTimings = durOnExerciseBike.getText().toString();

                DatabaseManager entry3 = new DatabaseManager(this);
                entry3.open();
                entry3.week1createEntry3(exerciseBikeTimings);
                entry3.close();

                String ellipticalTrainerTimings = durOnEllipticalTrainer.getText().toString();

                DatabaseManager entry4 = new DatabaseManager(this);
                entry4.open();
                entry4.week1createEntry4(ellipticalTrainerTimings);
                entry4.close();
```

Writing Entries in table `weekone`

```
//creating entry in table for treadmill in table week 1 with the help of ContentValues

public long createEntry(String treadmillTimings) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    //enterting each exercise name corresponding to their respective edit Texts

    cv.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, "Treadmill");
    cv.put(KEY_DURATION, treadmillTimings);

    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null,cv);

}

//creating entry in table for stepperTimings in table week 1 with the help of ContentValues

public long week1createEntry1 (String stepperTimings)
{
    ContentValues cv1 = new ContentValues();
    cv1.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, "Stepper");
    cv1.put(KEY_DURATION, stepperTimings);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null,cv1);

}

//creating entry in table for Stationary Rowing in table week 1 with the help of ContentValues

public long week1createEntry2 (String stationaryRowingTimings)
{
    ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
    cv2.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, "Stationary Rowing");
    cv2.put(KEY_DURATION, stationaryRowingTimings);

    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null,cv2);

}

//creating entry in table for exercise bike in table week 1 with the help of ContentValues

public long week1createEntry3 (String exerciseBikeTimings)
{
    ContentValues cv3 = new ContentValues();
    cv3.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, "Exercise Bike");
    cv3.put(KEY_DURATION, exerciseBikeTimings);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null,cv3);

}

//creating entry in table for elliptical trainer in table week 1 with the help of ContentValues

public long week1createEntry4 (String ellipticalTrainerTimings)
{
    ContentValues cv4 = new ContentValues();
    cv4.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, "Stationary Rowing");
    cv4.put(KEY_DURATION, ellipticalTrainerTimings);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null,cv4);

}
```

Displaying entries in database

```
//displaying/reading data in the table using cursor

public String week1getData() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_EXERCISENAME, KEY_DURATION};
    Cursor cur = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    //creating a result(string type variable) to store the text and display it.

    String result = "";

    int iRow = cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iExerciseName = cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXERCISENAME);
    int iDuration = cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_DURATION);

    // cursor start from the first position, keeps moving to the next as long as the position in not after that last.

    for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext())
    {
        /*getting the rows, exercise name and duration in the tables of database and setting it to result. 
          .The next time it loops, it will still have the prevoius result*/

        result = result + cur.getString(iRow) + "              " + cur.getString(iExerciseName) + "                            " + cur.getString(iDuration) + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}
```

All the code is same for table`weektwo` except for the below

```
public String week2getData()      <------- ERROR IS IN THIS METHOD, BASED ON LOGCAT
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_EXERCISENAME, KEY_DURATION};
    Cursor cur = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE2, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    //creating a result(string type variable) to store the text and display it.

    String result = "";

    int iRow = cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iExerciseName = cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXERCISENAME);
    int iDuration = cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_DURATION);

    // cursor start from the first position, keeps moving to the next as long as the position in not after that last.

    for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext())
    {
        /*getting the rows, exercise name and duration in the tables of database and setting it to result. 
          .The next time it loops, it will still have the previous result*/

        result = result + cur.getString(iRow) + "              " + cur.getString(iExerciseName) + "                            " + cur.getString(iDuration) + "\n";
    }

    return result;


}
```

Addtionally I did exactly the same for `weektwo`whatever i did for `weekone`. please tell me where am I going wrong. thanks

Comment: could you please post your logcat? Would like to see what specific error is it throwing..

Comment: As it was very long, please visit http://pastebin.com/k48xdSr9 to view the logcat. Furthermore, the method week2getData is in DatabaseManager.java

Comment: Can u please let us know excatly the point where it crashes ? Try debugging and post the

Comment: when it open the database view, it doesn't find the native method which I assume is because i have changed the orignal getData() to week2getData() but nor sure if that is that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saw your logcat and it seems that your database is closed when you try to read the data. I would like to suggest to not to open and close the database so frequently. This creates a lot of confusion in the code. You can try to open the database at onCreate of your parent Activity(the context that you pass) and close it in onDestroy() only.

EDIT: You can refer [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html) for design patterns.

EDIT 2 : You can confirm if this is the problem or not by opening the database only once and never closing it to see if the problem goes away. If it does the refer the linked article in previous edit.

Comment: Its partially working i-e, it showing me both table enteries in one, but I need it to show the enteries in seperate tables.